# MVC5 [Route] attribute for parameterless endpoint not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, url-routing

I have an MVC 5 application with an Angular front end.

I am having issues in calling parameterless endpoints.

The MVC application has a controller which the Angular application calls for data.

For example, I am able to call endpoints defined as:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/MyApplication/GetData/{id}")]
public ActionResult GetData(int id)
```

by using the following in Angular

```
const endpoint = 'localhost:0000/api/MyApplication/GetData' + '/' + 0);
return this.httpClient.get<JSON>(endpoint);
```

However, If I define the endpoint as

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/MyApplication/GetData/")]
public ActionResult GetData()
```

and use the following in Angular

```
    const endpoint = 'localhost:0000/api/MyApplication/GetData');
    return this.httpClient.get<JSON>(endpoint);
```

I get ta 404 error. The same is true when calling from Postman

Can you suggest how I can over come this?

Answer (score 0):

There is only an endpoint with '.../GetData/', none without the last forward slash: '.../GetData'. There simply is no matching route.

If you want a parameterless endpoint, just get rid of that last forward slash, like this:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/MyApplication/GetData")]
public ActionResult GetData()
```

If you want more control of the URL-parameters that are sent with the request, you can check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0).